# Why tf.gfile.Glob cost a lot of RAM?

Tags: tensorflow

I try to get files from remote hdfs and I find out if I call 'tf.gfile.Glob'， it costs me 10G RAM.

How can I avoid this since my input pipeline is multi-processed and I need as many processes as possible to get remote tfrecords fast enough!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug I reported some time ago: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23733

Certain versions of Tensorfow are affected. The one compiled by the tensorflow package maintainers in Archlinux and I found out that it also happens when installing tensorflow in a cuda environment.

Hence: try to change the tensorflow version / the environment you use, if you use conda.